# Anyone know how to *completely* destroy a UI5 instance?

Tags: unit-testing, sapui5

Trying to test my UI5 based app. I don't like the OPA stuff, so I've just been using QUnit. This is fine - works like it should. I would like to start from scratch with every module, so that tests do not pollute each other and I can start with a clean state. However, every time I make a new instance of my app, it's all `duplicate ID` errors (obviously...). `destroy()` gets rid of all DOM elements related to the app, but the active `core` is still alive and that's what seems to remember the previously created elements, so this solves nothing.

How can I restart UI5? My only alternative is to stick every module in their own HTML page, which is not awesome.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When I read your post I thought: Wow, If he is right, we have a serious memory leak problem on our hands.

But then I wrote a test... ;-)

http://jsbin.com/pocayekalu/5/edit?js,output

The above test just creates garbage controls with arrays of random numbers, simply polluting memory. After five seconds they are all destroyed and new ones are created - the last counter is rendered to the DOM.

Then I ran the profiler and watched the memory. It first grows up to a certain point, then it is freed regularly again:

[image: Chrome memeory profile]

What happens is, that as soon as you destroy a control, it is removed from the map in the core, which stores a reference to all controls by ID. **That does not mean that the Javascript object is destroyed - you can still hold a reference to the actual object.**

As soon as you remove all references to the control objects in your code, it still does not mean that the browser removes them from memory, that is done during the next garbage collector run, which might be started immediately or even never - depending on how much memory your app uses and what the browser engine thinks would be sufficient.

It is basically out of your control when exactly the browser engine decides to clean up. In the above test the browser is forced to run garbage collection since we force it to run out of memory otherwise.

Update:

If you have an App and all Controls are somewhere under the App's Control tree (meaning: All Controls are added to a parent's aggregation), simply destroying the App will also destroy all child Controls (and their children).

Comment: Haha! That is a great answer :-) I didn't mean this from the memory perspective per se: I meant that UI5 remembers all created elements. I think it keeps an array, and actively prevents an element with the same ID being generated. Is that what this describes?

Comment: Exactly. That is the "map in the core"that I described. When you invoke sap.ui.getCore().byId("abc"), the map has to contain all IDs of Controls that have not been detroyed. As soon as the Control is destroyed, another one with the same ID can be added to the Control Tree (and thus the Core's map) again.